fantasy book from 2012/13, young girl with powers from poorest part of kingdom, pursued by a captain
Okay, so I read this book when I was still in primary school which was almost 10 years ago, it is a fantasy book my memory of the plot is quite foggy at this point but from what I remember the protagonist was a young girl who had powers who lived in the poorest part of the kingdom. She didn't have any family except her brother/close neighbour/family friend who used to hunt in the woods so they had food. I think her powers were discovered because she tried to hide it and she was captured by huntsmen/soldiers and held captive at this camp. I think there was a head wizard or something I can't remember. I do remember it being a little mature for my age so it is probably a young adult book.

there was also a captain/general who was obsessed with her/her power and was trying to pursue her
a weird guard who tried to assault her a few times I think he was killed by the captain but I don't remember clearly.
I read this around 2012/13 so the book was published either a few years before or around that time.

This is the most I can remember about the book, I really hope someone knows the book im describing, any suggestions are helpful!!

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to remember the cover of the book at all?

Unfortunately not this was so many years ago, my best guess is there was a girl on the front cover.

Any chance this is : Shadow and Bone by Leigh Bardugo?

It's a very similar plot, but I don't remember there being any monsters involved in the plot. It's funny because I watched the show but it didn't remind me of the book I read but I'll try reading the book instead! Thanks.

Have you by any chance been looking for a trilogy by Trudi Canavan called The Black Magician trilogy? It's a story about girl, who live in the kingdom, but she is a commoner. She has magical powers.
The author of the question pointed out that the main character lives in the kingdom, namely in the poor part of the kingdom.
The main character is not a noblewoman and has magical abilities.
The main character does not seem to have biological parents, but has a guardian. All these elements are in the book. However, I have not read and do not know this trilogy myself. I just found this trilogy on a website about trails.

Can you explain in more detail how this trilogy matches the details provided in the question?

@Алексей Иванов - You don't need any more reputation than you have to comment on your own posts. You can do so by clicking on the 'Add a comment' link directly beneath your posts.

As a side note to that, if it seems like you can't comment on your own posts, especially as a new person, there's a decent chance that you initially posted with an unregistered account and now you're trying to comment with another new one. There are steps to merge them.

Thanks for help.
